# avoid gaps in graphics with float numbers C#

Tags: c#, xna, floating-point

I draw graphics using XNA in C#

```
View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0f, 100f, 0f), Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Forward);

Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(20.0f), ((Game1)Game).graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio, 1.0f, 10000.0f);
```

my camera never moves, only my games objet moves.
and I move them in the following way to get smooth motion

```
float speed = 0.001f;
pos.Z = pos.Z + (gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds * speed);
```

but, I have road tiles(Primitives VertexPositionTexture) to be rendered after the other to give the feeling of a road to drive on.

it works, but sometimes it's a pixel spacing between my road tiles which I do not want.
I think it has to do with the floating-point coordinates.

how should I work around this?

thanks in advance!
and I hope my explanation was clear about my problem.

edit 1: if someone wants to vote down this post, please comment why.
it is difficult to develop without feedback.

edit 2: info on Primitives.

res 400 x 50 on rod1

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace WindowsGame1
{
    class Rod
    {
        public static Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.VertexBuffer buffer;
        public static Texture2D[] tex;
        public static BasicEffect effect;

        public Vector3 pos;
        public int typ;

        public const float Width = 24f;
        public const float Height = 5;

        public Rod(Vector3 pos,Random r)
        {
            this.pos = pos;
            typ = r.Next(tex.Length);
        }

        static public void Initialize(GraphicsDevice g)
        {
            buffer = new VertexBuffer(g, VertexPositionTexture.VertexDeclaration, 6, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);

            VertexPositionTexture[] vertices = new VertexPositionTexture[6];

            vertices[0].Position = new Vector3(-Width, 0f, -Height);
            vertices[0].TextureCoordinate.X = 0;
            vertices[0].TextureCoordinate.Y = 0;

            vertices[1].Position = new Vector3(Width, 0f, Height);
            vertices[1].TextureCoordinate.X = 1;
            vertices[1].TextureCoordinate.Y = 1;

            vertices[2].Position = new Vector3(-Width, 0f, Height);
            vertices[2].TextureCoordinate.X = 0;
            vertices[2].TextureCoordinate.Y = 1;



            vertices[3].Position = new Vector3(Width, 0f, Height);
            vertices[3].TextureCoordinate.X = 1;
            vertices[3].TextureCoordinate.Y = 1;

            vertices[4].Position = new Vector3(-Width, 0f, -Height);
            vertices[4].TextureCoordinate.X = 0;
            vertices[4].TextureCoordinate.Y = 0;

            vertices[5].Position = new Vector3(Width, 0f, -Height);
            vertices[5].TextureCoordinate.X = 1;
            vertices[5].TextureCoordinate.Y = 0;

            buffer.SetData<VertexPositionTexture>(vertices);
            effect = new BasicEffect(g);
            effect.TextureEnabled = true;
        }

        public void SetTyp(Random r)
        {
            typ = r.Next(tex.Length);
        }

        public void Update(GameTime gameTime, Double speed)
        {
           // pos = new Vector3(pos.X, pos.Y, pos.Z + (gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds * speed) );
            pos.Z = pos.Z + (float)(gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds * speed);
        }

        public void Draw(Matrix View, Matrix Projection, GraphicsDevice g)
        {
            effect.World = Matrix.CreateScale(1.01f) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(pos);
            effect.View = View;
            effect.Projection = Projection;
            effect.Texture = tex[typ];

            foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
            {
                g.SetVertexBuffer(buffer);
                pass.Apply();
                g.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `double` or `decimal` instead

Comment: thanks Daniel Hilgarth ! , but it unfortunately gave no effect.

Comment: Its missing some important infos, like the drawing code. But my suggestion is to round the position and sizes of the tiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't pinpoint the problem without more details, but this is what is likely happening:

Say for example that you're drawing two rectangles. So if you draw each of them independently, you'll get something like this:

```
+--------+
|        |
|        |
+--------+  < gap greatly exaggerated
+--------+  <
|        |
|        |
+--------+
```

This could cause visible gaps.

What you want instead is something like this:

```
+--------+
|        |
|        |
+--------+
|        |
|        |
+--------+
```

Not in the sense of having no gap, but in the sense of **sharing vertices**.

In the top illustration, there are 8 vertices. In the bottom, there are 6, because vertices are shared between the rectangles. This means that it is impossible even in theory to have a gap, because there is only a single edge between the two.

What you need to do is refactor your code to share vertices between rectangles.

In graphics programming, this is often called a quad strip or triangle strip. Riemer has a [page](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series3/Triangle_strip.php) explaining triangle strips in the context of XNA.

Answer (score 0):

You could try transforming the textures with a Matrix.CreateScale(1.01f)

Also, are your textures being scaled, or sized correctly when initially created in your paint program? Scaling of textures in any case by floats can cause edge inaccuracies and should be avoided where possible.

Comment: "You could try transforming the textures with a Matrix.CreateScale(1.01f)" - works but feels like a bad solution, there are alternatives?

"Also, are your textures being scaled, or sized correctly when initially created in your paint program? Scaling of textures in any case by floats can cause edge inaccuracies and should be avoided where possible." - I'm not sure, I'll give out more code in my first post.